# MPI4Py: OpenMPI How to Update Dictionary across processes?

Tags: openmpi, mpi4py

In my scenario, I have an environment that I'm trying to sample from. Each process will sample multiple times from this environment.

```py
import numpy as np
class EnvSim(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        return np.random.randint(0, 2000)

from collections import defaultdict
class Dict(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = defaultdict(int)

    def update(self, key):
        self.d[key] += 1
        print(key)
        data_array = [np.empty(1, dtype=np.int) for _ in range(num_cpu)]
        data_array[proc_id()] = np.array([key], dtype=np.int)
        MPI.COMM_WORLD.Bcast(data_array[proc_id()], root=proc_id())
        for data in data_array:
            self.d[data.tolist()[0]] += 1
```

The goal is for each OpenMPI process to share what they've sampled from the environment synchronously or asynchronously. Is `Bcast` the right method to use here or should I use something else?

This is the main statement that I used to execute my program :( currently this is not working.

```py
def mpi_fork(n, bind_to_core=False):
    """
    Re-launches the current script with workers linked by MPI.

    Args:
        n (int): Number of process to split into.

        bind_to_core (bool): Bind each MPI process to a core.
    """
    if n<=1:
        return
    if os.getenv("IN_MPI") is None:
        env = os.environ.copy()
        env.update(
            MKL_NUM_THREADS="1",
            OMP_NUM_THREADS="1",
            IN_MPI="1"
        )
        args = ["mpirun", "-np", str(n)]
        if bind_to_core:
            args += ["-bind-to", "core"]
        args += [sys.executable] + sys.argv
        subprocess.check_call(args, env=env)
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_cpu = 3
    mpi_fork(num_cpu)

    dic = Dict()

    for _ in range(3):
        exp = EnvSim.get()
        dic.update(exp)

    print(dic.d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Synchronous case:

I'm not sure what you mean by "synchronously and asynchronously", so I'll just focus on the synchronous case here.

If you want all ranks to sample and send to everyone, then I think you want `alltoall` instead of `Bcast`.

Below is an example script where each `rank` samples `N` values from the interval `(rank,rank+1)`, where `N` is the size of the communicator.

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

senddata = np.random.uniform(rank,rank+1,size)
recvdata = np.empty(size, dtype=float)
comm.Alltoall(senddata, recvdata)

print("process %s sending %s receiving %s " % (rank,senddata,recvdata))
```

Instead of having the script launch itself, can you just call a directly form the command line with:

`$ mpirun -np 3 python test.py`

and you should see output such as

```
Rank 0 sent [0.37362478 0.74304362 0.25090876] and received [0.37362478 1.81852273 2.48959575] 
Rank 1 sent [1.81852273 1.65782547 1.85142608] and received [0.74304362 1.65782547 2.23064501] 
Rank 2 sent [2.48959575 2.23064501 2.644848  ] and received [0.25090876 1.85142608 2.644848  ]
```

This can be included in a `for` loop, if multiple rounds of sampling/communication are desired.

#### Asynchronous case:

If there is some expectation of variability in the times to sample, then you could have rank zero be a master and perform non-blocking queries of each of the remaining ranks. For example:

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

tag_denoting_ready_to_send = 1
while 1:
    if comm.rank == 0:
        if comm.Iprobe(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=tag_denoting_ready_to_send):
            buffer_for_receiving = np.empty(1, dtype='i')
            comm.Recv([buffer_for_receiving, MPI.INT], source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, tag=tag_denoting_ready_to_send)
            print(buffer_for_receiving[0])
    else:
        sleep(comm.rank*np.random.uniform())
        send_buffer = np.array(rank, dtype='i')
        comm.Send([send_buffer, MPI.INT], dest=0, tag=tag_denoting_ready_to_send)
```

Each non-zero rank is sleeping and trying to `Send` their rank in a buffer to rank 0 (which prints that out). Again, running with

```
$ mpirun -np 20 python test2.py
```

should yield output such as:

```
13
6
1
1
2
7
1
2
1
4
1
8
3
```